# Wifi interface keeps crashing for standard Ubuntu 16.04 installation on Lenovo i100

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I have a standard ubuntu 16.04 installation on a Lenovo ideapad 100.
On irregular intervals the laptop looses connection to the wifi router.

```
$ ip a show wlp3s0
```

shows only

```
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

but i cannot restart it with either of these commands, the interface remains down.

```
# ifconfig wlp3s0 up
# ip link set wlp3s0 up
# service network-manager restart
```

This happens in different wifi networks.

The wifi icon in the top right corner sometimes shows, that it is searching for a connection, but it is unable to connect.

Is this a problem of the driver, or is there also another chance to get it manually up again?

**Update**

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.     RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b728]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hey i got the output and updated the question